# How to change extracted specified range of text from Entry into another? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

```
phqitemmaintit["text"][0:8] = Font(fg="Red")
```

Above is the extracted text but `Font` and `fg` method are not working.

How can I fix it to color text of `Label`?

Comment: ```phqitemmaintit.config(fg="red")```? If you want to have different colors in one label, then I don't think you can unless you do some more logical work

Comment: If you use a `tkinter.Text` widget, you can use tags. They allow you to change the colour/font of a specific section of text. I don't think you can do that using a `tkinter.Label`

Comment: I must to sliced text to color unless if i do, more logical to complete page layout than before.

Comment: thank you I will do it

Comment: now i will try to change label into text. go go

Comment: @DevOpps Just something to help you: `text.tag_config("red_fg_tag", foreground="red")`, `text.tag_add("red_fg_tag", "1.0", "1.8")`. It creates a tag named `"red_fg_tag"` and then adds it to the first 8 characters of the text box.

Comment: I have an idea, make different labels of  same text and different colors and place them such that they overlap. It will be tedious tho

Comment: @PCM in that case there is no need for overlapping, just split text into labels, such as that a label contains only a part of the text, but yes, it will still be tedious and better to use `tkinter.Text` widget

Comment: thanks to your helping I solved this problem. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strings do not have fonts. You can't extract text and then add font information to it. At least, not in any way that python or `tkinter` can use it.

Font information is part of a widget, not part of the text. If you want to color part of a text string, the only supported way of doing that is with a `Text` widget, in which case you apply a tag to a range of characters and then configure that tag to have a color.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=1)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.tag_configure("red", foreground="red")
text.insert("end", "0123456789Hello, world")
text.tag_add("red", "1.0", "1.8")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]